# Gradle Task Not Running After Test

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have integration tests setup in my `build.gradle` file as such:

```
task integrationSetup(dependsOn: jar, type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$projectDir/resources/integration"
    commandLine 'sh', './start_service.sh'
}

task testIntegration(dependsOn: integrationSetup, type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.testIntegration.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.testIntegration.runtimeClasspath
    ignoreFailures = true
}

task integrationTearDown(dependsOn: testIntegration, type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$projectDir/resources/integration"
    commandLine 'sh', './stop_service.sh'
}

testIntegration.mustRunAfter integrationSetup
testIntegration.finalizedBy integrationTearDown
integrationTearDown.mustRunAfter testIntegration
```

However since upgrading the Gradle Wrapper to version 4+ the tasks no longer execute correctly. The final tear down never runs and the service continues. What has changed between version 3 and 4 to change this behaviour. Pretty upsetting Gradle did this without warning or deprecation notices.

One dumb option is to downgrade the Gradle wrapper version (can confirm this setup still works on 3.1).  But that shouldn't be necessary IMO.

UPDATE: Made some changes per user @Opal.  However still have issue where if any errors occur during integration tests the final tear down does not run.

```
> Task :compileTestIntegrationJava
Putting task artifact state for task ':compileTestIntegrationJava' into context took 0.0 secs.
file or directory '/home/project/cleaner/src/testIntegration/java', not found
file or directory '/home/project/cleaner/src/testIntegration/java', not found
Executing task ':compileTestIntegrationJava' (up-to-date check took 0.072 secs) due to:
  Output property 'destinationDir' file /home/project/cleaner/build/classes/java/testIntegration has changed.
  Output property 'destinationDir' file /home/project/cleaner/build/classes/java/testIntegration/com has been removed.
  Output property 'destinationDir' file /home/project/cleaner/build/classes/java/testIntegration/com/project has been removed.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':compileTestIntegrationJava'.
file or directory '/home/project/cleaner/src/testIntegration/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/home/project/cleaner/src/integration/java/com/project/cleaner/CleansRequestsTests.java:415: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error

:compileTestIntegrationJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 8,5,main]) completed. Took 0.162 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestIntegrationJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 8s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
```

Comment: The dependencies are not configured well, should be: `testIntegration.dependsOn integrationSetup testIntegration.finalizedBy integrationTearDown` - but since it doesn't work could you please run gradle with `-i` switch and verify the output for the tasks? It should be written if task is executed or not and why.

Comment: That should work also with gradle > 4.0. just tested it with gradle 4.3.1. probably the tear down task is not executed directly after testIntegration but later in the graph? as @opal suggest, please provide the output of the `-m` run of your build

Comment: Opal is right, for your usecase `dependsOn` on the setup and `finalizedBy` on the tear down should be sufficient.

Comment: The reason I had that setup in that manner was it proved most affective in working if any errors or issues were encountered during the integration tests.  If something failed I still want the service to be turned off.  I just don't get why it works for one version but not the latest.

Comment: The teardown is not being executed at all or at least in the correct order @Rene The process continues to run when the integration tests fail or if they succeed.

Comment: @Opal your structure allows the whole process to complete but it does not stop the service after the integration tests are complete.  I tried this with successful tests and tests that cause the test suite to stop early, both had same result.  The `stop_service.sh` file was never executed.

Comment: @MarkII, have you run it with at least `-i` and `-m`. Please do it and verify the output.

Comment: My apologies, skipped right past that.  @Opal I did run it with -i and -m, Gradle is saying it is running that task and that file successfully.  So that would lead me to believe something within stop_service file is wrong or at least no longer operational as it was before, which now I'm testing.

Comment: @MarkII, do you have an example to try it out?

Comment: @Opal figured it out, the directory from which it was executing changed, got it to work when all tests pass.  However my original problem isn't 100% solved.  The stop_service runs only if the integration tests are successful, any runtime errors or issues and the tear down never runs.

Comment: Confirmed with `-i` integrationTearDown never executes. @Opal

Comment: @MarkII, but what is the reason it doesn't execute? Paste the log output.

Comment: @Opal sure.  The tests fail because I'm purposely putting a compile time error in one of test suites.  I need to make this fool proof since other developers tend to Murphy's Law this project.

It won't let me in comments...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158630/discussion-between-opal-and-markii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discussion it turned out that OP wants to stop the service started before running test no matter what e.g. compilation errors. It can be done with the following script:

```
ext.integrationTearDown = { 
  workingDir "$projectDir/resources/integration" 
  commandLine 'sh', './stop_service.sh' 
} 

task(type: Exec, 'stop_service', integrationTearDown) 

gradle.buildFinished { 
  exec integrationTearDown 
} 

testIntegration.dependsOn integrationSetup 
testIntegration.finalizedBy stop_service
```

With this piece of code the service will be stopped after *every* build - event if it succeeds. To avoid this behaviour [`BuildResult`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildResult.html) which is passed to `buildFinished` may be used to determine the required behaviour.